# Using OneDrive to create PC back up

Tags: onedrive

I've just migrated from Google Drive to OneDrive. On Google Drive, there was a feature where chosen folders on your laptop were automatically backed up on the cloud when changes occurred, but the files also stayed local. I'm trying to implement something similar with OneDrive, but I'm having some issues. You don't seem to be able to choose which files stay local and which don't - it's either all or none. Additionally, when I create a backup of my PC, it just throws it into the general folder. If instead I change the folder location, it for some reason then shows all my OneDrive files under my local documents.

**What I'm after:** I want OneDrive to automatically upload files to the cloud from chosen folders, but also keep those files locally. I don't want to be able to see other OneDrive folders in my local documents folder.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] . Here tags should added  based on what is being asked, not about the words included in question. Anyway, the question is better suited for [su].

Comment: OneDrive most certainly supports uploading directories with the OneDrive folder.  Sounds like part of your issue is that your synchronizing your user profile directories by accident.

Comment: OneDrive defaults to uploading specific folders and you can add others. And you can tell it to keep any of those on your computer by right clicking on them and choosing the appropriate option.